# Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY returning NULL even though valid proximity sensor is present

Tags: android, proximity

I am writing a test app to validate the Proximity sensor functionality on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet (Wifi only). As per the device specification it supports a proximity sensor . How ever when I query for the supported sensors on the device it does not return a proximity sensor and hence the sensor of type `sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY` is null . Is there any other way to validate proximity functionality other than using this class? Wondering why this would return null when the device spec clearly says that it supports proximity sensor.

Relevant piece of code :

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY); //This returns null
List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY); //returns null
```

Comment: Some "proximity" sensors are really just light sensors with a dynamic cutoff. Have you tried looking into that? I can't say I've played with a Note, but some devices' light sensors report a simple 0/1 for near/far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that you have sensor for proximity. If you do then try to do something after implementing SensorEventListener.  I face the same problem with my tablet, and at the end came to conclusion that I don't have proximity available in my tablet.

Comment: Thanks . Yes I did try implementing the sensor event listener as below but since mSensor was null it never really worked . My piece of code . Have you tried something similar ?                                                      mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);                                            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

Comment: NO ACTUALLY I DID NOT . I LEFT IT FOR TIME BEING TO FOCUS ON SOME OTHER APPS